# Servlet on startup that triggers an event after regular interval of time using timer class?

Tags: java

I have a servlet that starts on start of tomcat. I need a functionality in that servlet that triggers the event after a regular interval of time i.e 1 hour and
runs in the back ground? Here  is my  code :-

in main method

```
MyTask contentTask = new MyTask();
 long interval = 60 * 60 * 1000;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(contentTask, new Date(), interval);//line 1
 System.out.println("line2");//line2
```

MyTask

```
public class MyTask extends TimerTask {
 @Override
 public void run() {
System.out.println("Inside my task");

}
}
```

i am expecting as soon control comes to line 2 , run method gets executed and then it keeps on execting the task after ever 60 minutes like background thread does. But
    control does not come to  run method after line 2. **I am not sure what i am missing here and why run method is not getting executed?**

**Edit:-  I think problem is with interval value if i make it one minute i.e 1 * 60 * 1000; contol comes to run method . Looks like even the first time task will be executed after specified time interval  i.e 60 minutes but i want to execute the task immediately as soon as it executes the line 1 and then repeat it after 60 minutes How to go for this?**

Comment: Did you try delaying start time by say 500ms? like `timer.schedule(contentTask, new Date(new Date().getTime()+500), interval)`?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should start as daemon. [`new Timer(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#Timer%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking for a ServletContextListener. You can execute code at the deployment before everything else. In this code you use Executors instead of a "Vanilla" Thread, and schedule it.

```
@WebListener
public class GlobalContext implements ServletContextListener {
    private ServletContext app;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    //What to do when app is deployed
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        //Init Context
        app = event.getServletContext();
        //In my case I store my data in the servlet context with setAttribute("myKey", myObject)
        //and retrieve it with getAttribute("myKey") in any Servlet

        // Scheduler
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AutomateRefresh(), 0, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);      
    }

    //Do not forget to destroyed your thread when app is destroyed
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }

    //Your function
    public class AutomateRefresh implements Runnable {
        public void run() {

            //Do Something

        }
    }

}
```

FYI, Executors is part of Java 5 and further.